# NFA Containing 'a'

Tags: computer-science, automata

I have L={Contains 'a'} and Alphabet(E)={a,b}

Can i create a NFA Like this

[image]

Comment: You can create an NFA like that, sure, but that one doesn't accept $L$, it accepts all nonempty strings of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @BrianO okay got it.Say the string is bb, there will be transition from Q1 to Q2 (but no 'a') still ,it gets accepted.So i need an Edge labelled a from Q1 to Q2.Q1 and Q2 having edges labelled a,b to them.

Comment: That's right. However, there's no reason to have two edges labelled $a$ from Q1, one edge looping to Q1 and the other advancing to Q2. Just use one edge Q1 -> Q2 on $a$. The machine will actually be a DFA.

Comment: @BrianO Please take a look here and let me know if he is wrong https://youtu.be/ZjjAbFxjxLQ?t=3m5s

Comment: I didn't say it's *wrong*, it's just unnecessary, and can be further simplified, as described. In that machine (in the vid), it's nondeterministic which $a$ of a string transitions to the accepting state. If instead the $Q_1$ edges are $Q_1\stackrel{b}\to Q_1$ and $Q_1\stackrel{a}\to Q_2$, then the transition to $Q2$ always happens on the first $a$ in an accepted string. This machine is deterministic and even has one fewer transition.

Comment: @BrianO Okay.He is describing the examples of NFA in that Video.I get your point though.Thanks

Comment: True. It's not a great example of why NFAs are useful. They're useful when they make it *easier* to describe a language!  DFAs *are* NFAs, and why confuse people with needless transitions? But enough said. As mentioned, it's correct, but in this case there's a simpler NFA, which happens to be deterministic.

Comment: @BrianO Alright.Thanks..

Comment: @BrianO Can you please check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553139/nfa-containing-01-as-substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-empty string winds up in Q2 and stays there, so you match more than you should. For example, $bbb$ is accepted even though it's not in $L$.

The initial state should keep reading input until $a$ is read, and the other one should be the accepting state and just consume the rest of the input by looping any input to itself.

Comment: Sorry i forgot drawing the second circle.Please see the update.

Comment: Say the string is bb, there will be transition from Q1 to Q2 (but no 'a') still ,it gets accepted.So i need an Edge labelled a from Q1 to Q2.Q1 and Q2 having edges labelled a,b to them.

Comment: @techno Thanks for the update - but the second part of my answer is still appropriate. I'll modify the first part to update on the current image.

Comment: @techno Yeah, that's correct. But you need to remember to loop Q1 --> Q1 if you read a $b$, because otherwise you'd reject a string for containing a $b$ which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this and let me know if he is wrong https://youtu.be/ZjjAbFxjxLQ?t=3m5s

Comment: @techno Yeah, he is. The $a$ in Q1 --> Q1 isn't really necessary, but is allowed in NFA. He does make a mistake later in the video by forgetting to set the accepting state for $L_5$, though.

Comment: But when you say that it will reject a string containing b there is a transition  marked to Q1 on accepting either a or b,So how does it reject a string containing 'b'? Do you have any contradiction to support your argument.

Comment: @techno The transition Q1 --> Q2 shouldn't happen with $b$. The transition to the accepting state Q2 should only happen when $a$ is read, not with $b$.

Comment: It does not happen.It only happens when reading a .

Comment: See this screencap http://imgur.com/t7JqF7S

Comment: @techno Yes, that's one way to create a correct automaton.

Comment: That's is what shown in the Video

Comment: So i understand that there is no need to have a transition a,b from Q1 to Q1.I just need a transition on 'b' from Q1 to Q1.But i hope the thing shown here http://imgur.com/t7JqF7S is correct even if it contains an extra transition on Q1

Comment: @techno You're right, it is correct. Just $b$ would be enough on Q1 -> Q1 but $a, b$ is correct too. If you leave $a$ out on the Q1 -> Q1 transition, it's a DFA which may be desirable at times.